# Celery acknowledge unregistered tasks

Tags: python, celery

I am looking to ignore unregistered tasks, i.e when a task received without a method implemented with its name, message will be acknowledged and the following error will not be raised

```
Received unregistered task of type..
```

I'm implementing Multiple Receivers pattern, i.e one service is calling different service tasks using `send_task` celery method, while all the services in the system are getting the same messages as well

Comment: You actually DO want the exception to be thrown! Making it like "nothing happened" is just going to cause you headaches in the future...

Comment: No, I'm calling methods from different code bases (microservice) using celery_app.send_task, sending method name as string. All microservices will get all the messages, i.e there will be tasks that are not relevant to different services

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem, by simply over-riding the original method that handles this case:

```
from celery.worker.consumer import Consumer

def on_unknown_task(self, body, message, exc):
    task_name = message.headers.get('task')
    task_id = message.headers.get('id')
    print(f'[on_unknown_task] Ignoring and acknowledging message for '
          f'unknown task. Task name: {task_name}, Task id: {task_id}')
    message.ack()

Consumer.on_unknown_task = on_unknown_task
```